# Why was Samantha Carter on SG-1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

It seems unusual to me, of any of the characters, that Carter was on SG-1. While she is extremely smart, and a reasonably good fighter, her strength is in gate physics and other similar stuff. As most of the complex gate activity occurred on the Earth side of the gate, it seems highly unusual that she would be sent so frequently into so many potentially dangerous situations, where her unique skills wouldn't necessarily be of any benefit.  It seems like an electronics expert might have been a better choice to fulfill her position. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can only guess for this one, but wasn't she also the leading expert on the Stargates at the time?  Which would make her the most qualified to fix off-world Gates if something went wrong.

Comment: Also, not sure if this applies but women weren't allowed in combat situtions in the military until recently, though not sure if it applied to covert units etc.

Comment: @Izkata: True enough, but most of the time when there was a problem, it was on Earth. Besides, none of the other SG teams that I am aware of had a remotely expert in that area, and they would be just as likely to have problems...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - Sam was a person of action.  Sitting behind the desk has never suited her.  Even when she got promoted off the team she found ways into the action when ever she could.  That type of person needs to be in the thick of it to be effective.  Its like having a great race horse but keeping it back so you always have a good back up... it loses its edge and abilities.

Comment: @Chad: Still, if I were in charge, I would have placed her on one of the research teams, IE, if there is some cool new piece of technology found, call them to investigate it.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - Sounds like you would have fit in with the IOA more than SGC

Comment: Why can't we just accept a simple answer.  She was doing it because she wanted to. I would be pretty surprised if SGC positions were not entirely voluntary.  Perhaps she wasn't interested in sitting back in a lab 24/7, studying things other people found.

Comment: @NominSim I believe it not assigned to a front-line unit, not no combat, if the base/ship is attacked it doesn't matter if you are male or female, you are supposed to help defend it.

Comment: @ewanm89 Yes, but SG1 certainly *was* **the** front-line unit.

Comment: <sarcasm>I know right? Even her reproductive organs were on the inside! Jeez!</sarcasm>

Comment: @NominSim True. But I think technically being a front-line unit was after she joined, I mean, technically in the movie and first episode they are only exploring and happen to run into trouble. Not actively planning on ending up in a combat zone.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Samantha Carter wasn't just a scientist.  It's often forgotten that she was an pilot and logged over 100 hours over enemy territory in the Gulf War ([Stargate Wiki Article](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Samantha_Carter)).  While she's brilliant, she's also proven herself in the field as a pilot, which includes meaning she's in top physical shape and has fast reflexes.

She also has a Small Arms Marksmanship Medal from the USAF, as well as several other medals she's earned for her abilities.

She's just as highly qualified to be out in the field as she is to be in a lab.  That helps SG1, specifically, because they have someone who can analyze alien technology quickly and put it to use, but they're not giving up a combat trained team member to do that.  She is often the first person with hands on experience with many technologies and it's better to have a scientist/engineer in that position than someone without that training.

Samantha Carter is a "double threat."  Not only does she excel as a scientist, but even before the formation of SG1, she had proven she was able to handle combat.

Comment: "she was an enemy pilot"??? I must have missed THAT detail

Comment: @DVK: You could have just edited the darn thing instead of letting me know how senile I am.

Comment: That goes against my self-inflicted vow to never eradicate senility

Comment: @DVK: Does that apply to yourself as well?  That might explain a lot...

Comment: what were we talking about again?

Comment: @DVK: Thanks for proving my point.

Answer (score 7):

Carter wasn't just the expert on Stargates, she was a leading expert on alien technologies in general, which would make her a prime asset in the field.  And I can remember quite a few episodes where they had problems with Stargates in the field, not just on Earth.

From the few appearances of other SG teams, most of them also had a scientist of some sort on their teams.  The only exception I can remember off hand was I recall a team making an appearance or two that was comprised of Marines.

It would make sense for the SG-C to operate two kinds of teams.  One type being a mix of combat and scientist and the other type being purely combat/commando type teams for insurgent strikes and as backup for the primary teams.

Comment: There are at least 4 types, namely primary research, exploration, pure military, and mining, but...

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, the question should be why are any of the other guys allowed to be on the same team as Carter.  She is by far the most powerful member of SG-1.  Her biggest problem is that she holds back.  Replicarter saw that as the defining difference between them.  Sam is a badass soldier, pilot, and one of the most gifted scientists on the planet.  What more could she possibly do to qualify for the team?

Answer (score 3):

The answer that I told myself was that a big part of the mission of SG-1 is to find new alien technology. They probably can't safely take everything back with them (what if it's an aquata bomb, or guarded by alien hostiles or something), so they need her skills to analyze it in the field. Thus it's worth risking her to assess these things.

She's also good with the gate, but they can probably find other gate nerds to help if things go wrong.

Comment: Do you mean "naqahdah"?